# Is it true Visual Studio 2010 will support PHP for free?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010

I have read this here

http://www.codeplex.com/php4vs

but can't find any official confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

In this thread, [Native Support for PHP in Visual Studio 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/b0c178f4-e306-4bab-b0e7-281442537280), it's said:

> Visual Studio 2010 will NOT natively
>   support PHP coding... 
> There are
>   external add-ins to Visual Studio like
>   [VS.PHP](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) which can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will not be supported out of the box with Visual Studio 2010, but you can add PHP support with this free project: [VS.PHP](http://svn.jcxsoftware.com/)

Comment: It's good practice to first check if your answer was already given by someone else.

Comment: VS.PHP is definitely not free ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5) which is free (with an option to purchase additional features); from my experience - much faster, smarter and stable (in contrast to VS.PHP).